# Excluding the profile provider, is there an easy way to add custom fields to ASP.NET membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

I know you can use the Profile provider for custom fields, but given the way the data is stored in the database, it is not efficient for my needs.

Is there a way to add custom fields to the database for use with membership, while taking advantage of all the built in membership stored procedures and c# classes?  (Short of adding fields to the table, and modifying all the procedures and methods)

Thanks!
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the Table Profile Provider, here is a link: http://www.asp.net/downloads/sandbox/table-profile-provider-samples/.  This might solve you problem, since it stores each value in a single column insteal of a single column like the default provider.