# Changing asp.net membership configuration

Tags: asp.net, membership

I have created an ASP.NET site on Visual Studio 2010. Membership tables are coming automatically. On the "register.aspx" page, there are only three fields which are user name, email address and password. But in the register step, I want member to give me more information about himself such as name, surname, city, grad school and so on... I have added extra textboxes to the page and corresponding fields to table "aspnet_Membership".

After a little bit browsing the codes, I have found the providers section in "web.config" file. And I tried to add some parameters for my specific fields. But it did not work.

What if I need to add more data fields to membership table? For example I need to know the city the member lives. What can I do for this circumstance?

The membership node of web.config is the following:

```
<membership>
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
enablePasswordReset="true"
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
requiresUniqueEmail="true"
maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
passwordAttemptWindow="10"
applicationName="/"
/>
</providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013663/excluding-the-profile-provider-is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-custom-fields-to-asp?rq=1 will help me, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the built in MembershipUser and add custom fields.
Then you need to create a table to store the information and at last you need to create a custom membership provider. 
More information at msdn: [How to: Implement a Custom Membership User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx)